# Ploting correct colors with ggplot and geom_map

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I have this data frame called regional:

```
                       id         Growth    interv  color
1              ALENTEJO CENTRAL   479.11  (475,500] yellow
2              ALENTEJO LITORAL   530.23 (525, Inf] green4
3                       ALGARVE   470.91  (450,475]    red
4                 ALTO ALENTEJO   499.72  (475,500] yellow
5                    ALTO MINHO   519.31  (500,525]  green
6                   ALTO TÂMEGA   460.50  (450,475]    red
7  ÁREA METROPOLITANA DE LISBOA   494.05  (475,500] yellow
8   ÁREA METROPOLITANA DO PORTO   497.15  (475,500] yellow
9                           AVE   484.41  (475,500] yellow
10               BAIXO ALENTEJO   461.79  (450,475]    red
11                  BEIRA BAIXA   511.19  (500,525]  green
12    BEIRAS E SERRA DA ESTRELA   503.52  (500,525]  green
13                       CÁVADO   486.08  (475,500] yellow
14                        DOURO   509.93  (500,525]  green
15              LEZÍRIA DO TEJO   514.67  (500,525]  green
16                   MÉDIO TEJO   504.39  (500,525]  green
17                        OESTE   488.85  (475,500] yellow
18                 R. A. AÇORES   461.74  (450,475]    red
19                R. A. MADEIRA   490.16  (475,500] yellow
20             REGIÃO DE AVEIRO   490.46  (475,500] yellow
21            REGIÃO DE COIMBRA   502.82  (500,525]  green
22             REGIÃO DE LEIRIA   507.60  (500,525]  green
23               TÂMEGA E SOUSA   452.97  (450,475]    red
24     TERRAS DE TRÁS-OS-MONTES   454.03  (450,475]    red
25             VISEU DÃO LAFÕES   514.99  (500,525]  green
```

and I am trying to plot a map with the colors in the last column (regional$color) with this code:

```
niv_leg=c("<450","]450; 475]", "]475;500]","]500; 525]", ">525")
colors = c("red4", "red", "yellow", "green", "green4")

prtnutsiii = ggplot()+
  geom_polygon(data = mapaf, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group), fill = NA, colour="darkgray", size=0.25)+
  coord_equal()

growth = prtnutsiii +
  geom_map(data = regional, map = mapaf, aes(map_id = id, fill =  color),colour="darkgray", size = 0.25) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors,labels = niv_leg)
pisamathg + theme(legend.position = "left")
```

I get this map:
[image]

But I am facing two problems and I can't figure them out:

1. I only get 4 labels in the legend (they should be 5)
2. The colors are not ploted correctly at all for the different "id" regions...

The "id" in the mapaf match the "id" in the regional dataframe so, I have no clue why it does not work... Any help will be appreciated.

P.S.: The shp file (mapaf) I am using is here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/112525/mapaf.txt

This is the dput(regional):

```
structure(list(id = c("ALENTEJO CENTRAL", "ALENTEJO LITORAL", 
"ALGARVE", "ALTO ALENTEJO", "ALTO MINHO", "ALTO TÂMEGA", "ÁREA METROPOLITANA DE LISBOA", 
"ÁREA METROPOLITANA DO PORTO", "AVE", "BAIXO ALENTEJO", "BEIRA BAIXA", 
"BEIRAS E SERRA DA ESTRELA", "CÁVADO", "DOURO", "LEZÍRIA DO TEJO", 
"MÉDIO TEJO", "OESTE", "R. A. AÇORES", "R. A. MADEIRA", "REGIÃO DE AVEIRO", 
"REGIÃO DE COIMBRA", "REGIÃO DE LEIRIA", "TÂMEGA E SOUSA", "TERRAS DE TRÁS-OS-MONTES", 
"VISEU DÃO LAFÕES"), MATHMEAN = c(479.11, 530.23, 470.91, 499.72, 
519.31, 460.5, 494.05, 497.15, 484.41, 461.79, 511.19, 503.52, 
486.08, 509.93, 514.67, 504.39, 488.85, 461.74, 490.16, 490.46, 
502.82, 507.6, 452.97, 454.03, 514.99), interv = structure(c(3L, 
5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("[-Inf,450]", "(450,475]", 
"(475,500]", "(500,525]", "(525, Inf]"), class = "factor"), color = structure(c(3L, 
5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("red4", "red", "yellow", 
"green", "green4"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", "MATHMEAN", 
"interv", "color"), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: try `scale_fill_identity()`

Comment: you should also really simplify the polygons. this is a high level choropleth and you'll speed up rendering

Comment: Thanks hrbrmstr. Adding `scale_fill_identity()` gets me the correct colors. But I loose the customized legend... will look at the help to see if there is a workaround?  I did use `fortify`to simply the map data... You are refering to something else?

Comment: you can change the legend with the `labels` parameter to `scale_fill_identity()`. `foritfy()` won't simplify the polygons. you need to use `gSimplify()` for that or find a better shapefile. You don't need precise coastline detail for a macro choropleth and it'll plot much faster. there are many examples for simplifying a shapefile on SO and on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
names(colors) <- niv_leg
```

Before the `ggplot` call. Without the names, the mapping order may be different, which is what is leading to your issue (I believe). I would also try running it without setting the labels first to make sure they are coming through in the same order.

If you add the code to read in your data (e.g. with `dput`) and how you loaded/prepared your shapefile, I could play with solutions directly.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply Mark. I will add the dput

Comment: The shape file was loaded from this file:  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/112525/PRT__NUTS_ALL.shp    with this code      `mapa<-readShapeSpatial(file.choose())`  and then  `mapa@data$id=regional$id
mapaf=fortify(mapa, region="id")`

Comment: @JPMD or even better, simulate this with a few squares or use a dataset that comes with R in a minimal, reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Following @hrbrmstr suggestion, I believe I got a working solution: Add

```
scale_fill_identity("Média", labels = niv_leg, breaks = colors,
                  guide = "legend")
```

somewhere after the `geo_map(...)`

Thank you all for the feedback. I am just wondering why the `scale_fill_manual` messes up the colors... I guess it is interpreting colors as a factor and not the true name of the colors...